# Yii2 Access denied (ForbiddenHttpException) to backend controller

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I installed new Yii advanced framework. Nginx server.

Below url is working fine:
http://yii/backend/web/index.php?r=site/index

I created new CRUD using GII and accessed:
http://yii/backend/web/index.php?r=user/index

It showing below error:

```
An Error occurred while handling another error:
exception 'yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException' with message 'You are not allowed to perform this action.' in /private/var/www/yii/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/filters/AccessControl.php:151
Stack trace:
#0 /private/var/www/yii/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/filters/AccessControl.php(134): yii\filters\AccessControl->denyAccess(Object(yii\web\User))
#1 /private/var/www/yii/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/ActionFilter.php(71): yii\filters\AccessControl->beforeAction(Object(yii\web\ErrorAction))
#2 [internal function]: yii\base\ActionFilter->beforeFilter(Object(yii\base\ActionEvent))
#3 /private/var/www/yii/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php(541): call_user_func(Array, Object(yii\base\ActionEvent))
#4 /private/var/www/yii/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(263): yii\base\Component->trigger('beforeAction', Object(yii\base\ActionEvent))
#5 /private/var/www/yii/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Controller.php(108): yii\base\Controller->beforeAction(Object(yii\web\ErrorAction))
#6 /private/var/www/yii/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(149): yii\web\Controller->beforeAction(Object(yii\web\ErrorAction))
#7 /private/var/www/yii/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(455): yii\base\Controller->runAction('error', Array)
#8 /private/var/www/yii/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/ErrorHandler.php(85): yii\base\Module->runAction('site/error')
#9 /private/var/www/yii/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/ErrorHandler.php(109): yii\web\ErrorHandler->renderException(Object(yii\web\NotFoundHttpException))
#10 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleException(Object(yii\web\NotFoundHttpException))
#11 {main}
Previous exception:
exception 'yii\base\InvalidRouteException' with message 'Unable to resolve the request "user/index".' in /private/var/www/yii/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php:461
Stack trace:
#0 /private/var/www/yii/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php(84): yii\base\Module->runAction('user/index', Array)
#1 /private/var/www/yii/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(375): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#2 /private/var/www/yii/advanced/backend/web/index.php(18): yii\base\Application->run()
#3 {main}

Next exception 'yii\web\NotFoundHttpException' with message 'Page not found.' in /private/var/www/yii/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php:96
Stack trace:
#0 /private/var/www/yii/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(375): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#1 /private/var/www/yii/advanced/backend/web/index.php(18): yii\base\Application->run()
#2 {main}
```

Did i missed any configuration?

Comment: could be some error in path using gii...

Comment: @scaisEdge related files are generated in correct path

Comment: check the permissione for vendor diir be sure you have executable permission for everyone

Comment: provide full controller code

Answer (score 0):

Yii2 isset AccessControl

```
public function behaviors()
{
return [
    'access' => [
        'class' => \yii\filters\AccessControl::className(),
        'only' => ['create', 'update'],
        'rules' => [
            // deny all POST requests
            [
                'allow' => false,
                'verbs' => ['POST']
            ],
            // allow authenticated users
            [
                'allow' => true,
                'roles' => ['@'],
            ],
            // everything else is denied
        ],
    ],
];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> exception 'yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException' with message 'You are not
>   allowed to perform this action.' in
>   /private/var/www/yii/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/filters/AccessControl.php:151

**Here is yii2 code**

```
    /**
     * Denies the access of the user.
     * The default implementation will redirect the user to the login page if he is a guest;
     * if the user is already logged, a 403 HTTP exception will be thrown.
     * @param User $user the current user
     * @throws ForbiddenHttpException if the user is already logged in.
     */
    protected function denyAccess($user)
    {
        if ($user->getIsGuest()) {
            $user->loginRequired();
        } else {
            throw new ForbiddenHttpException(Yii::t('yii', 'You are not allowed to perform this action.')); 
//this is 152 line
        }
    }
```

So I think its very clear that you need to login first, so go to http://yii/backend/web/index.php?r=user/login.

If dont have login user/login  page then remove all `behaviors` section at the top of your UserController.

```
    public function behaviors()
    {
.
.
.        
    }
```